# Derivative of order 16 - is there a method to do so?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have the following exercise:

> Find the $16^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $y$, (i.e. $y^{(16)}$), for $y = \sin x$.

Is there any method to do so, or I simply have to differentiate the function $16$ times?

Comment: hint: $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\sin x = -\sin x$.

Comment: Did this question deserve a downvote? I don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$y'=\cos x$

$y''= -\sin x=-y$

$y'''=- \cos x=-y'$

$y''''=\sin x=y$

Do you notice the recursion? $y^{4k}= \dots $?

Comment: I do. guess it's $sinx$? thanks!